# Where to define error code constants in C++

Tags: c++, qt, dllexport, error-code

I have exported a method from a C++ DLL and then call it from a VB.net forms application. The C++ method currently has no return value (void) but I want to improve it and return an int that represents a series of error codes. (I plan to return zero if all went well.)

Where and how is the best place to define these error codes?

Should I do the following at the top of my CPP file:

```
#define ERR_NEGATIVE_CELL_SIZE 1
#define ERR_INVALID_FILE_PATH 2
etc
```

The VB.net application will also define these same codes and then show UI messages to the user based on the code.

Obviously I would prefer to throw an exception in the DLL and catch it (along with the relevant exception message) in VB.net, but this doesn't seem to be possible using the extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) method.

Happy to hear about alternative design patterns. I also plan to expose the DLL methods via a C++ console executable, so storing the error messages once in the DLL and having them available to both the console and UI applications is ideal.

Answer (score 4):

Please avoid the preprocessor wherever possible.

For your scenario, defining an enum would be reasonable.
Define it next to the function prototype.
For exposing the translations, use a translation function and export that too.
Something like:

```
size_t TranslateError(int error, char* buffer, size_t size)
```

Returns: size of the translated message, message in the buffer if return <= len

Answer (score 4):

If you want the error codes to be available to other compilation units then they are best placed in a header file. Typically when writing library code you would create one or more header files that declare all the constants, types, functions and classes that are needed to use the library. The implementations are then compiled into the library. The consumer of the library includes your headers and an import library.

Regarding your constants, you are proposing using `#define` to declare them. Don't do that. Consider using constants or enums. The pre-processor is generally something to use as little as possible.